# Excel Count /Unique Dynamic Array

Tags: arrays, excel, count, unique

I need to count unique values between two columns I have tried count(Unique())formula.

Results entered all values instead of separate value with column

Input :

```
Date       Name 
1/1/2022    A
1/1/2022    A
1/1/2022    B 
1/2/2022    B
```

Output :

```
Column D  Column E 
A          1 
B          2
```

Comment: You could try something like `=LET(X,UNIQUE(B2:B5),CHOOSE({1,2},X,BYROW(X,LAMBDA(A,COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A5,B2:B5=A)))))))`. Very similar to @Scottcraner's answer. Otherwise, just load the data into an pivot-table. It has a function to count unique values just fine. No need for formulae. Make sure to tick "Add this data to the Data Model".

Answer (score 2):

Use LET with BYROW and LAMBA in a FILTER:

```
=LET(dt,A2:A5,nme,B2:B5,unqnme,UNIQUE(nme),unqall,UNIQUE(CHOOSE({1,2},dt,nme)),cnt,BYROW(unqnme,LAMBDA(a,COUNT(FILTER(unqall,INDEX(unqall,0,2)=a)))),CHOOSE({1,2},unqnme,cnt))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: @Prakriti please edit your original post to include any clarifications, please do not try to put clarifications in comments.

Comment: =COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER($A$2:$A$5,D2=$B$2:$B$5))) - Tried already - Does not work . I am trying to group this result into the format given above  !                                             
Following Line of Code works : =LET(dt,A2:A5,nme,B2:B5,unqnme,UNIQUE(nme),unqall,UNIQUE(CHOOSE({1,2},dt,nme)),cnt,BYROW(unqnme,LAMBDA(a,COUNT(FILTER(unqall,INDEX(unqall,0,2)=a)))),CHOOSE({1,2},unqnme,cnt))  Thankyou for all your help

Answer (score 2):

### UNIQUE DISTINCT COUNT

Well, earlier the query was bit confusing, although it was clear that OP needed Unique Distinct Count, but wasn't sure whether needed those colons `:` in between and `Name` in beginning or not . However here is another way you may also try.

• Formula used in cell **D2**

```
=UNIQUE(B2:B5)
```

• Formula used in cell **E2**

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER($A$2:$A$5,D2=$B$2:$B$5)))
```

Alternative formula to get unique distinct counts

• Formula used in cell **F2**

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF($B$2:$B$5=D2,MATCH(A$2:A$5,A$2:A$5,0)),ROW(B$2:B$5)-ROW(B$2)+1)>0))
```

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

Comment: =COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER($A$2:$A$5,D2=$B$2:$B$5))) - Tried already - Does not work . I am trying to group this result into the format given above :

Comment: But the image clearly shows it works, however you should try the solution provided by @ScottCraner Sir

Comment: @Prakriti please show us a screenshot where it is not working for you

Comment: =COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER($A$2:$A$5,D2=$B$2:$B$5))) - Tried already - Does not work . I am trying to group this result into the format given above  !                                             
Following Line of Code works : =LET(dt,A2:A5,nme,B2:B5,unqnme,UNIQUE(nme),unqall,UNIQUE(CHOOSE({1,2},dt,nme)),cnt,BYROW(unqnme,LAMBDA(a,COUNT(FILTER(unqall,INDEX(unqall,0,2)=a)))),CHOOSE({1,2},unqnme,cnt))  Thankyou for all your help

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question, maybe this can help you:
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(A2:A5&B2:B5))
A column is date and B column is Name

Comment: Thankyou ! =COUNTA(UNIQUE(A2:A5&B2:B5))-will add all the columns . My expection for result :

Comment: Thankyou ! yes  Colume -A  - Date , Column -B - Name =COUNTA(UNIQUE(A2:A5&B2:B5))-will add all the columns for A, B . My expection for result is A =  1 and B =2 coz  refering first example as no of date entered result on Column B - should be change .

Comment: So you need for each name how many entries are different in date?

Comment: Yes I was able to execute result with Lambda line of Code. My goal on this task is to executed multiple entries with Multiple date and expected output count. I did not get any results with following code                                                                              
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF($B$2:$B$5=D2,MATCH(A$2:A$5,A$2:A$5,0)),ROW(B$2:B$5)-ROW(B$2)+1)>0))